# Yesod-platform installation failing because of Alex package

Tags: haskell, ubuntu, cabal, yesod, cabal-install

I'm trying to update the yesod platform to the latest version. In order to do this, I have executed the following commands:

```
cabal update
cabal install yesod-platform yesod-bin
```

To which I eventually get the following error:

```
Resolving dependencies...
Configuring language-javascript-0.5.13...
cabal: The program alex version >=3.0.5 is required but the version found at /usr/bin/alex is version 3.0.1
cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
hjsmin-0.1.4.6 depends on language-javascript-0.5.13 which failed to install
language-javascript-0.5.13 failed during the configure step. The exception was:
ExitFailure 1
yesod-platform-1.2.12.2 depends on language-javascript-0.5.13 which failed to install
yesod-static-1.2.4 depends on language-javascript-0.5.13 which failed to install
```

After a bit of research, I have stumbled on the [following post](http://www.yesodweb.com/book/haskell) which mentions I should install a few more dependencies manually before doing the `cabal install yesod-platform yesod-bin` command. Those dependencies include `alex` amongst others. This, unfortunately, did not help as I got the same errors when I tried again.

I have then noticed that the version of `alex` in my `/usr/bin/alex` is still 3.0.1 after the manual install of `alex` version 3.0.5. After a bit of research, it seems when installing that package, it installs it in the `$HOME/.cabal/bin` and that path was not in my `$PATH` variable, so I added it in the `/etc/environment` file before the the entry `/usr/bin/`. After a reboot of my server, I have once again tried, but still get the same error.

Even if I added `$HOME/.cabal/bin` before `/usr/bin/`, it still goes in the latter to look for `alex`, which seems to be the problem. Other than copying the executable of `alex` version 3.0.5 from `$HOME/.cabal/bin` to `/usr/bin/` manually (which I'm scared would cause me some problems, and headaches when wanting to update in the future), what could I do? Is this the real problem here?

Also, as a side question, when I `echo $PATH`, the $HOME is not resolved to `/home/<myusername>` (I see `$HOME/...`), is this normal?

EDIT: Tried renaming `alex` to `alex.bak` in `/usr/bin/` to try and "force" ubuntu to take the one from `$HOME/.cabal/bin`, but it now cannot find any program named `alex`. Why is it not finding it in `$HOME/.cabal/bin`?

Comment: what does `alex --ver` say? - Normaly if you setup your path correctly it should work. Anyway you can tempor. change your complete path `export PATH=/home/[you]/.cabal/bin` and retry. As a final remark: you can copy alex it should be no problem - but maybe the one in /usr/bin is just a symlink anyway.

Comment: Your path seem to be flawed - try setting it right there in the console the way I said before. BTW: I think the `alex` comming with the current plattform (soon there will be a new one) is `3.1.0` (you did `cabal update` and `cabal install alex`right? (just seen - the current one is `3.1.3`)

Comment: @CarstenKönig It was indeed my path that was flawed as I added it using `export` and it worked. The problem though is that `export` is not permanent (it will revert back after a reboot). Why isn't $HOME registering properly in the `/etc/environment` file? Isn't that the right way to set the `$PATH` variable for it to stay after a reboot? And yeah, the version of my alex is 3.1.3 when I do `alex --ver`, so it is up to date now.

Comment: you can add the same line to a file named `/home/[you]/.profile` - it will do it for you at login - most likely this file already exists and you just have to append the line without `export` (for example `PATH="$HOME/.cabal/bin:$PATH"`)

Comment: concerning the $HOME - this env. var might not be set when you did your export (depends on where you did it) - I usually just put in the complete path just to be extra save ;)

Comment: @CarstenKönig Thanks for your help! If you want, you can add that as an answer and I shall set it as the answer to this question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As it turned out the problem was just the usual path problems.
`Cabal` installs new executables like `alex` into

`/home/[you]/.cabal/bin` (or `~/.cabal/bin`) on linux

So you should set up your path to look there first.

You can to this temporary by writing

`export PATH=/home/[you]/.cabal/bin:$PATH` in your terminal before doing any **Haskell** stuff but normaly you might want to add this to a login-script.

The best place for this is IMO `/home/[you]/.profile` (or `~/.profile`) so edit this file (or create it if it does not exist) and add these lines to the end of the file:

```
if [ -d "$HOME/.cabal/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/.cabal/bin:$PATH"
fi
```

As this one takes care of the `$HOME` var to it should work just fine.
Of course this one will only work after you loged in again.

You can test it with

`whereis alex` and `alex --ver` - the first one should point you to this path too, the second one should print out your current version of alex.

Have fun.

PS: replace `[you]` with your name within Linux everywhere of course ;)